# How to implement a SQL Server persistance layer in Orbeon Forms?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, orbeon

I'm getting ready to create an Orbeon persistence layer for Microsoft SQL Server. I think that it can be similar to MySQL persistence layer. What would be best way to create it: would you recommend I write my own Java code from scratch, or modify the existing MySQL persistence code, in XPL?

Comment: Question is too broad. Basically it is open ended and not specific enough.

Answer (score 0):

I would indeed recommend you modify the [MySQL persistence implementation](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/tree/master/src/resources/apps/fr/persistence/mysql) and adapt it for SQL Server. And then, once it is working for you, if it is OK with you, you could contribute your implementation to the open source project, and it will then be maintained and distributed by default with Orbeon Forms.

And if you have any particular difficulty programming this, feel free to post questions about this on Stack Overflow or on the [Orbeon Forms list](http://discuss.orbeon.com/).

Comment: I have decided to write own persistance layer in Java. I hope that it will end successfully. Regards

Comment: OK, this is certainly possible as well. But still have a look at the current MySQL implementation. Even if you're not familiar with XPL/XSLT, I think you'll find it relatively easy to adapt it for SQL Server, and that it will be less work overall than rewriting code in Java.

Comment: HyperLink for mySql persistence source (https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/tree/master/src/resources/apps/fr/persistence/mysql) veiws the 404 error. Is there posibility to get this code? Is there some kind of tutorial, how write persistence in xpl (I mean which files I have to write on my own), or can You give me some advice where I can find some good solution/help with writing? Regards